# Object has no attribute 'entry_set' error

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm new to Python, trying to work through Python Crash Course and I've run into a problem that I can't figure out. Here's my error:

**'Pizza' object has no attribute 'entry_set'**

In my model I have the foreign key defined to Pizza in Toppings and it works fine, but I apparently don't understand the `entry_set` definition.

Here's my URL code:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'pizzas'

urlpatterns = [
    # home path
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # show all pizza names
    path('names/', views.names, name='names'),
    # show all pizza toppings
    path('toppings/', views.toppings, name='toppings'),
    # show a pizza and it's toppings
    path('names/<int:name_id>/', views.pizza, name='pizza'),
]
```

Here's my view code (as you can see, I have the `entry_set`):

```
def pizza(request, name_id):
    """Show a single pizza and all it's toppings"""
    name = Pizza.objects.get(id=name_id)
    toppings = name.entry_set.order_by('topping')
    context = {'name': name, 'toppings': toppings}
    return render(request, 'pizzas/pizza.html', context)
```

And lastly, my HTML code:

```
{% extends 'pizzas/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

  <p>{{ name }}</p>

  <p>Toppings:</p>

    <ul>
      {% for topping in toppings %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ topping|linebreaks }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

Here's the models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Pizza(models.Model):
    """Pizza names """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.name


class Toppings(models.Model):
    """Pizza toppings """
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    topping = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.topping
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects might be of help

Comment: Could you show us `Pizza's` definition in code?

Comment: Sure! Here it is, Helena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pizza and Topping model have a Many-to-One relationship. That is what a "ForeignKey" relationship is. There are two different tables (among many others) in your database. One for Pizza and one for Toppings. What a ForeignKey relationship does is put a column in your Topping table that points to a row in your Pizza table. It is a way to associate the entries in those tables to each other.

If you have Topping instance:

```
pepperoni.pizza
```

will return the pizza.

What you're asking about is how to go the other way. To have a pizza instance and then get the toppings. To get all of the rows in your Toppings table with a Pizza column that points to an instance of Pizza.

There is something in Django called a related_name you can define it as such:

```
class Toppings(models.Model):
    """Pizza toppings """
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='toppings')
```

with that you can then do this:

```
afternoon_pizza.toppings.all()
```

to return all the toppings on afternoon_pizza. The default related_name is the 'name_of_your_model' + '_set'. So without the above modification you could get the same results with:

```
afternoon_pizza.toppings_set.all()
```

My best guess is that the example in your book has a field that is called "entry".

The django docs do a much better job than I do explaining this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, Art. That is a great explanation. And you're right, the example in the book does have a field called "entry". Guess that's why I couldn't find "entry_set" in Google! Lol

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `entry_set` in this line:

```py
toppings = name.entry_set.order_by('topping')
```

and you must use
`foo_set` where `foo` is the class name (e.g.,`toppings`?) in lower case

```py
toppings = name.toppings_set.order_by('topping')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would think it should have an `entry_set`. The only model related to Pizza is Topping, and you haven't set a custom `related_name` on the ForeignKey, so a pizza has a `topping_set`.

Comment: I just search "related_name" and found that if it's not defined, Python takes the name of the model and creates one. So, does that mean I should use pizza_set? I tried that and it didn't work either, "Pizza' object has no attribute 'pizza_set". Maybe I'll try adding a related_name even tho I shouldn't need one.

Comment: No, I told you what it was: `topping_set`. The related_name refers to the reverse relationship. A pizza has a set of toppings, not a set of pizzas or entries.