# Topic.entry_set Issue [Django]

Tags: python, django, django-models

I tried the fix from here but it still won't work.
[ReverseManyToOneDescriptor object has no attribute order_by django 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51909428/reversemanytoonedescriptor-object-has-no-attribute-order-by-django-2-1/62083658#62083658)

What am I missing? 
entering http://localhost:8000/topics/1/ gives me

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/topics/1/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'learning_logs')
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Personal projects\python\learning_log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\Personal projects\python\learning_log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\Personal projects\python\learning_log\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\Personal projects\python\learning_log\learning_logs\views.py", line 20, in topic
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')  # lowercase "t"

Exception Type: AttributeError at /topics/1/
Exception Value: 'Topic' object has no attribute 'entry_set'
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Topic


def index(request):
    """The home page for learning log"""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')


def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)


def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')  # lowercase "t"
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Where is the issue? how can I use entry_set?

Thanks.

Comment: @ did you check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714887/object-has-no-attribute-entry-set-error ]?

Comment: Yes. didn't udnerstand. please clarify what I need to do.

Comment: yeah sure, please add your model as well.